# rosjava Cmake errors

Tags: ros, client-rosjava, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am currently trying to test rosjava in cturtle using the wiki provided at: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava_jni .

After running the "make test" command while in the , I am receiving the following error:

CMake Error: The **current CMakeCache.txt directory /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/client_rosjava/test_rosjava/build/CMakeCache.txt** is different than the directory **/tmp/buildd/ros-cturtle-client-rosjava-0.1.3/debian/ros-cturtle-client-rosjava/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/client_rosjava/test_rosjava/build** where CMackeCache.txt was created. This may result in binaries being created in the wrong place. If you are not sure, reedit the CMakeCache.txt
CMake Error: The source **"/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/client_rosjava/test_rosjava/CMakeLists.txt"** does not match the source **"/tmp/buildd/ros-cturtle-client-rosjava-0.1.3/debian/ros-cturtle-client-rosjava/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/client_rosjava/test_rosjava/CMakeLists.txt"** used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.

I have limited knowledge of the CMake and make commands, but I do know that Cmake is essentially a special case of the make command and essentially compiles multiple files of a project.

Any pointers?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10333/rosjava-cmake-errors/) by [Seanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/654/seanth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't run "make test" for packages that are installed via apt-get.  They are binary/read-only.  The "make test" example is only if you install client_rosjava from git.

In other words, don't worry about the 'make test' part of the docs and just continue with the rest of the examples.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Seanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/654/seanth/) on 2011-06-24**:
Thanks for your reply